# Invalid IMEI after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, imei

After factory reset my phone starts showing "Invalid IMEI" on both sim slots and I can't call or be called. What might be the problem?

Android version; 2.2.1 , model: A601

Comment: What is A601? I can only find a [missile ship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge_%28A601%29) (doesn't run on Android),  a [WiFi router](http://www.router-faq.de/index.php?id=ebinfo&hwe=easyboxa601), and a [Motorway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A601%28M%29_motorway)... Ah, you probably mean [this China phone](http://www.everychina.com/f-z51d9d09/p-90230152-a601_android_os_shake_screen_dual_sim_card_smart_phone_with_google_map.html)?

Comment: @Izzy Oooh! I like the China Phone :P
AFAIK, this error results from fake IMEI's. Did you try rolling back and checking the IMEI again? Maybe another factory reset?

Comment: It could be that this manufacturer's way of storing the IMEIs for the dual SIMs is not preserved across factory resets, so the reset has deleted the IMEI.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a Mediatek (which usually cleared IMEIs after flashing), you can try entering the IMEIs (found on the retail box) manually using `*#*#3646633#*#*`, and finding the option in Radio settings. I can't be sure if this works with newer MTK devices.